# ng click usando angular y google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Buena tarde, cordial saludo, queria comentar que cuento con el siguiente problema; estoy trabajando con angular y google maps con la directiva ng-map y tengo mi html, mi app.js y mi controller.js y no me funciona el ng click pero cuando lo hago todo en una sola pagina si me funciona, alguna recomendación? muchas gracias, mi codigo es el siguiente.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="premarca">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZLRPtun19mn3xqSZi08dPp-1R4P2A2B4&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController as vm">
    <div>
        <ng-map zoom="4" center="-28, 137.883">
            <map-data
                set-style="vm.styleFunc" 
                on-click="vm.onClick()"
                load-geo-json="data/ciudades.json">
            </map-data>
        </ng-map>
    </div>
    <button ng-click='buttonClick()'>Enviar</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='app.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='controller/mainController.js'></script>

</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('premarca', ['ngMap']);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller("mainController", function(NgMap,$scope) {
    var vm = this;

    alert('hola');

    var radioValue={};

    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        vm.map= map;
    });


    vm.onClick= function(event) {
        alert('hola');
    };

    $scope.buttonClick = function (){
        alert('hola');
    };
});//end aplication
```

Answer (score 1):

Ten cuidado al usar las funciones del controller dentro de los *views* cuando usas `controllerAs`. Hay que homogeneizar el código y usar `controllerAs` (prefiero este) o `$scope`.

Cambia

```
<button ng-click='buttonClick()'>Enviar</button>
```

por

```
<button ng-click='vm.buttonClick()'>Enviar</button>
```

y tu método

```
$scope.buttonClick = function (){
    alert('hola');
};
```

por

```
vm.buttonClick = function (){
    alert('hola');
};
```

Comment: muchisismas gracias, me funciono perfecto xD

Comment: @jcave de nada, si pudieras marcar entoces mi respuesta como correcta, te agradeceria.